# Why does my python code think that this character is bigger than another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to create a robot that plays "Big 2" card game.

My goal was to start off with making it only play 1 card plays. I am trying to test it out, returning `True` if number 1 is bigger than number 2 and `False` if it is not.

```
RANK_ORDER = '34567890JQKA2'
SUIT_ORDER = 'DCHS'

def is_higher(card1, card2):
  a = list(card1)
  b = list(card2)
  if a[0] == b[0]:
    if a[1] > b[1] in SUIT_ORDER:
      return True
    elif a[1] < b[1] in SUIT_ORDER:
      return False
  elif a[1] > b[1] in SUIT_ORDER:
    return True
  elif a[1] < b[1] in SUIT_ORDER:
    return False
  elif a[1] == b[1]: #problem may be from here downwards
    if a[0] > b[0] in RANK_ORDER:
      return True
    elif a[0] < b[0] in RANK_ORDER:
      return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(is_higher('8D', '9S'))
  print(is_higher('2S', '2D'))
  print(is_higher('3H', '2H')) #this has a problem
  print(is_higher('QS', 'JS'))
  print(is_higher('AD', '2S'))
```

I have somewhat succeeded in my goal, however, why does it return `True` for third example even though `3` is higher than `2` in `RANK_ORDER`?

Comment: As you already have a good answer, I will point out that the `a=list(card1)` is unnecessary. You can use the index values to access, e.g. `card1[0]` without first converting to a list.

Comment: Id also recommend you look at itertools.product to generate all possible cards before comparison

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not comparing what you think you're doing, you're comparing the ascii value of `a`'s suit to either 1 or 0 based on the boolean answer to if `b[1]` is in the suit order, you should compare their indices.

```
SUIT_ORDER.index(a[1]) > SUIT_ORDER.index(b[1])
```

And similarly for rank order comparisons

Comment: I was really amazed by the code and thought "Wow, I had no idea python can do that!". Turns out. It can't. At least not in that way. Thank for putting me back into reality @Sayse :D

Comment: Now I get "False, True, None, None, False"

Comment: @GuyOverThere - Thats because alot of your comparisons don't make sense, alot of them prioritise suit order over rank order, and theres a couple paths where you haven't defined what should happen when none of the if/elif statements are entered hence the none's. I'm not familiar with that card game so can't really help further